# Highcharts - Dynamic + Multiple charts not rendering

Tags: highcharts

I want to draw multiple highcharts on same page, which have dynamic data sent from server.
I created multiple charts, fed data to them dynamically, but only the last chart gets rendered, all others are blank.
I checked the chart object, data is **added** but not **plotted**.
Moreover, I extended the "Load Random data" to 3 charts, I got the same problem.
Following is my code:

```
var create = function(id){
document.body.innerHTML += "<div id='c"+id.toString()+"'></div>";
$('#c'+id.toString()).highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'spline',
            animation: Highcharts.svg, // don't animate in old IE
            marginRight: 10,
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Live random data'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            tickPixelInterval: 150
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Value'
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.series.name + '</b><br/>' +
                    Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) + '<br/>' +
                    Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        exporting: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Random data',
            data: (function () {
                // generate an array of random data
                var data = [],
                    time = (new Date()).getTime(),
                    i;

                for (i = 1; i <= 0; i += 1) {
                    data.push({
                        x: time + i * 1000,
                        y: Math.random()
                    });
                }
                return data;
            }())
        }]
    });
}

function init(){
    create(1);
    create(2);
    create(3);
    setInterval(function(){
        for(var i=1;i<Highcharts.charts.length;i++){
            var chart = Highcharts.charts[i];
            var series = chart.series[0];
            var x = (new Date()).getTime(),
                y = Math.random();
            series.addPoint([x,y], true);
        }
    },1000);
}
```

Here is the same code on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hrily/m9k4eb42/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are adding new divs to document's body is not working properly. You could (since you are loading jQuery) use jQuery's [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

```
$(document.body).append("<div id='c"+id.toString()+"'></div>");
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/m9k4eb42/1/